# How to integrate the following extreme value type function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate the following function.
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}yf(y) =\int_{x}^{\infty}y\bigg(1 + \xi\big(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\big)\bigg)^{-(1+1/\xi)}\exp\bigg(-\bigg(1 + \xi\big(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\big)\bigg)^{-1/\xi}\bigg)dy$$
where $f(y)$ is Generalized Extreme Value disstribution. I did a substituition that $u = 1 + \xi\big(\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma}\big)$ . Then I got the following.

$$\int_{s}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{\sigma(u-1)}{\xi} + \mu\bigg)u^{-(1+1/\xi)}\exp(-u^{-1/\xi}) \frac{\sigma}{\xi} du $$

where $s = 1+ \xi \big(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\big)$. I tried different substitutions, but I couldn't solve this integral. Could you please give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: I doubt that I closed form exists, unless you're willing to count the incomplete Gamma function. However, you might be able to find asymptotic expansions for your integral as $s\to 0$, or $s \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete solution**

For $\xi\neq0$ and $\xi<1$, and by introducing
$$\tau_x=\left ( 1+\xi \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right )^{-1/\xi}$$
then,
$$\int_{x}^{\infty}yf(y)dy=\left ( \mu - \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \right )\left ( 1-e^{-\tau_x} \right ) + \frac{\sigma}{\xi}\cdot\gamma\left ( 1-\xi,\tau_x \right )$$
Where $\gamma()$ is the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Indefinite_and_definite_integrals). It can be also written according to Gamma distribution CDF, if you environment can easily compute it
with a shape equal to $(1-\xi)$ and a rate equal to 1
$$\left ( \mu - \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \right )\left ( 1-e^{-\tau_x} \right ) + \frac{\sigma}{\xi}\cdot CDF_{gam}\left ( 1-\xi,1,\tau_x \right ) \cdot \Gamma\left ( 1-\xi \right )$$
Where $\Gamma(1-\xi)$ is the classic gamma function.

**PROOF**

By supposing you want to compute this integrale for a statistical issue. According to this,

if $\xi<0$, then $-\infty < x \leq \mu- \frac{\sigma}{\xi}$, and $\int_{x}^{\infty}yf(y)dy=\int_{x}^{\mu-\sigma/\xi}yf(y)dy$

else if $\xi>0$, then $\mu- \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \leq x < \infty$, no change.

Let introduce,
$$t(y)=\left ( 1+\xi \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma} \right )^{-1/\xi}$$
so,
$$dt=-\frac{1}{\sigma} \left ( 1+\xi \frac{y-\mu}{\sigma} \right )^{-1/\xi-1} dy$$
and finally (note that in your question the factor $1/\sigma$ is missing to define GEV PDF),

$$\int yf(y)dy=-\int \left ( \left ( t^{-\xi}-1 \right )\frac{\sigma}{\xi}+\mu \right )e^{-t}dt$$

Integration boundaries have to be considered differently according to $\xi$ value.

For $\xi<0$, $t(\mu-\sigma/\xi)=0$, and $\tau_x=t(x)$. Furthermore, x can tend to limit
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \tau_x = +\infty$$

For $\xi>0$, we can keep $\tau_x=t(x)$ definition, but limit to the infiny has to be considered for the 2nd boundary
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow +\infty} t(y) = 0$$
And in case that x tend to the GEV lower boundary
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \mu-\sigma/\xi} \tau_x = +\infty$$

Finally, for any $\xi\neq0$,
$$\int yf(y)dy=-\int_{\tau_x}^{0} \left ( \left ( t^{-\xi}-1 \right )\frac{\sigma}{\xi}+\mu \right )e^{-t}dt$$

We can reverse boundaries thanks to "-" sign and separate the two parts,
$$\int yf(y)dy=\left (\mu -\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right )\int_{0}^{\tau_x} e^{-t}dt + \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \int_{0}^{\tau_x} t^{-\xi}e^{-t}dt$$

And the really end,
$$\int yf(y)dy=\left (\mu -\frac{\sigma}{\xi}\right )\left ( 1-e^{-\tau_x} \right ) + \frac{\sigma}{\xi} \int_{0}^{\tau_x} t^{(1-\xi)-1}e^{-t}dt$$

Where the remaining integrale is by definition the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Indefinite_and_definite_integrals) $\gamma(1-\xi,\tau_x)$, and finite for $\xi<1$
It can be compute by [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) CDF with a shape equal to $(1-\xi)$ and a rate equal to 1 if needed
$$Gam_{CDF}(1-\xi,1,\tau_x)=\frac{\gamma(1-\xi,\tau_x)}{\Gamma(1-\xi)}$$

**What about $\xi=0$**

By a similar approach, with $\theta_x=e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}}$
$$\int yf(y)dy=\mu-\sigma \int_{0}^{\theta_x}\ln(t) e^{-t}dt$$

To do so, it seems possible to have some consideration on [derivative incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Derivatives), based on [Meijer G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function)... out of my skills!

Comment: Are they any other method to find the approximate solution?

Comment: Do you mean a numerical approximate solution?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks!

Comment: If you look for numerical approximation, a lot of math software can do so (e.g. [Scilab](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/integrate.html), or [Matlab](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), or [SmathStudio](https://en.smath.com/cloud/sheet/)), or trying Monte Carlo method by generating large amount of random variable according to your parameters: $\left \langle Y_i \right \rangle_{Y_i>x} \cdot \left ( F(Y_{max})-F(x)  \right )$, but again take care about your GEV boundary $\mu-\sigma/\xi$

Comment: I re-edited my answer because I succeed in estiablishing the connection with incomplete gamma function! I often use GEV distribution for professional usage, and I felt upset to see that I did not know it as much that I thought...Now, you can easily have a numerical result based on accurate evalution (even on Excel) of gamma distribution CDF.

Comment: Thank you so much!